# Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test

Tags: kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I have a data set and keep getting $D=1$ when I use the KS-Test. It doesn't matter what distribution I use. For example, consider the following:

```
ks.test(data,"pnorm")
ks.test(data,"pexp")
```

For these, I get:

```
  D = 1, p-value < 2.2e-16
  alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

The data I have looks exponential. Yet the KS-Test shows the opposite. Why?

Comment: It's impossible to tell without a look at your data. Can you show a density plot or box plot or something?

Comment: It appears to me you are misusing `ks.test`.  According to its manual page, you need to supply parameters for the named distribution. Without them, `pnorm` will default to a standard normal distribution and `pexp` will default to an exponential with rate $1$. But beware! It is invalid to supply parameters that have been estimated from the data themselves--see the last paragraph of the "Details" section.